# How to find Relevent Features for Comparing Diagrams(Images)?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, svm, feature-detection, feature-extraction

Currently we are doing a project on diagram comparison using SVM. Diagrams mainly include flow charts and block diagram.we are stuck on determining relevant features for training the SVM. The problem is that diagram and its components to be compared can be of various scales.  Please help for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In regard solely to the difference in scales:  this seems relatively straightforward. Set up classifier(s) based on the characteristics of the images in terms of the shapes/ pixel densities/ arrangements of artifacts. Those aspects are scale-independent.  You may also wish to introduce rotation and shear invariant capabilities into the svm.